# How to made vagrant to install php > v.5.4?

Tags: php, vagrant, chef-solo, vagrantfile

I configured a vagrantfile to install php >= v.5.4 via chef-solo.
But I get some troubles.
Tell me please if I am downloading some cookbook for chef provision can I modify something inside them, or I have just to configure the Vagrantfile???

This is my vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_PI_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10", auto_config: true
  config.vm.synced_folder "./shared", "/var/www"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'apt-get update'
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
     chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
     chef.add_recipe "apache2"
     chef.add_recipe "apache2::mod_rewrite"
     chef.add_recipe "mysql::server"
     chef.add_recipe "mysql::client"
     chef.add_recipe "php::source"

     chef.json = {
        :mysql => {
            "server_root_password" => ''
        },
        :apache => {
            "default_site_enabled" => true
        },
        :php => {
            "install_method" => "source",          
            "version" => "5.5.19",
        },
     }
  end
end
```

This is cookbook/php/recipes/source.rb:

```
configure_options = node['php']['configure_options'].join(' ')

include_recipe 'build-essential'
include_recipe 'xml'
include_recipe 'mysql::client' if configure_options =~ /mysql/
include_recipe 'yum-epel' if node['platform_family'] == 'rhel'

pkgs = value_for_platform_family(
  %w{ rhel fedora } => %w{ bzip2-devel libc-client-devel curl-devel freetype-devel gmp-devel libjpeg-devel krb5-devel libmcrypt-devel libpng-devel openssl-devel t1lib-devel mhash-devel },
  %w{ debian ubuntu } => %w{ libbz2-dev libc-client2007e-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfreetype6-dev libgmp3-dev libjpeg62-dev libkrb5-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng12-dev libssl-dev libt1-dev },
  'default' => %w{ libbz2-dev libc-client2007e-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfreetype6-dev libgmp3-dev libjpeg62-dev libkrb5-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng12-dev libssl-dev libt1-dev }
  )

pkgs.each do |pkg|
  package pkg do
    action :install
  end
end

version = node['php']['version']

remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/php-#{version}.tar.gz" do
  source "#{node['php']['url']}/php-#{version}.tar.gz/from/this/mirror"
  checksum node['php']['checksum']
  mode '0644'
  not_if "which #{node['php']['bin']}"
end

if node['php']['ext_dir']
  directory node['php']['ext_dir'] do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0755'
    recursive true
  end
  ext_dir_prefix = "EXTENSION_DIR=#{node['php']['ext_dir']}"
else
  ext_dir_prefix = ''
end

bash 'build php' do
  cwd Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]
  code <<-EOF
  tar -zxf php-#{version}.tar.gz
  (cd php-#{version} && #{ext_dir_prefix} ./configure #{configure_options})
  (cd php-#{version} && make && make install)
  EOF
  not_if "which #{node['php']['bin']}"
end

directory node['php']['conf_dir'] do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
end

directory node['php']['ext_conf_dir'] do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
end

include_recipe "php::ini"
```

But it doesn't work. This is the throwed error:

```
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Error executing action `create` on resource 'remote_file[/var/chef/cache/php-5.5.19.tar.gz]'
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch
==> default: ----------------------------------
==> default:
==> default: Checksum on resource (378de1) does not match checksum on content (8d39f2)
==> default:
==> default: Resource Declaration:
==> default: ---------------------
==> default: # In /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/php/recipes/source.rb
==> default:
==> default:  42: remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/php-#{version}.tar.gz" do
==> default:  43:   source "#{node['php']['url']}/php-#{version}.tar.gz/from/this/mirror"
==> default:  44:   checksum node['php']['checksum']
==> default:  45:   mode '0644'
==> default:  46:   not_if "which #{node['php']['bin']}"
==> default:  47: end
==> default:  48:
==> default:
==> default: Compiled Resource:
==> default: ------------------
==> default: # Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/php/recipes/source.rb:42:in `from_file'
==> default:
==> default: remote_file("/var/chef/cache/php-5.5.19.tar.gz") do
==> default:   provider Chef::Provider::RemoteFile
==> default:   action "create"
==> default:   retries 0
==> default:   retry_delay 2
==> default:   default_guard_interpreter :default
==> default:   path "/var/chef/cache/php-5.5.19.tar.gz"
==> default:   backup 5
==> default:   atomic_update true
==> default:   source ["http://us1.php.net/get/php-5.5.19.tar.gz/from/this/mirror"]
==> default:   use_etag true
==> default:   use_last_modified true
==> default:   cookbook_name :php
==> default:   recipe_name "source"
==> default:   checksum "378de162efdaeeb725ed38d7fe956c9f0b9084ff"
==> default:   mode "0644"
==> default:   not_if "which php"
==> default: end
```

What can you suggest me?
If I have to show more code, please tell, because I'm just the beginner with vagrant.

Comment: The step in Vagrantfile are fine, could you please paste the content in `cookbooks/php/recipes/source.rb`?

Comment: I have modified the question. Thanks. Hope you will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not answer currently, but I need paste some codes for asking further question..

The problem is on this part:

```
remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/php-#{version}.tar.gz" do
  source "#{node['php']['url']}/php-#{version}.tar.gz/from/this/mirror"
  checksum node['php']['checksum']
  mode '0644'
  not_if "which #{node['php']['bin']}"
end
```

The error is :

```
Checksum on resource (378de1) does not match checksum on content (8d39f2)
```

the gz file is downloaded from `http://us1.php.net/get/php-5.5.19.tar.gz/from/this/mirror` and save to `/var/chef/cache/php-5.5.19.tar.gz`

Could you manually download again, and check with below command to confirm if they are same (md5 or md5sum, depend your system)

```
md5 /var/chef/cache/php-5.5.19.tar.gz

or 

md5sum /var/chef/cache/php-5.5.19.tar.gz
```

Here is the md5 result from the gz file I download from internet. They should be same.

```
$ md5 php-5.5.19.tar.gz
MD5 (php-5.5.19.tar.gz) = 8ef89261aa6bb2d74df8d147f0d183a1
```